# Return data to from multiple queries in a single structure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have to create a screen, which has data fetched from multiple different tables using complex joins etc. There will be only one service call from the UI to fetch the data, which will be returned in JSON.

These are the approaches that came to my mind

1. Execute multiple queries from the service layer and populate an object and send the JSON object back.
2. Create a temp table, populate the data required as when the original data is updated, and query the temp table when the above screen is displayed.

For me both the approaches are not convincing. I don't want multiple database calls from service layer or to create temp table for this purpose. Rather, I am thinking to have one stored procedure which will execute multiple queries and return a custom structure, which can be mapped to a Java object which in turn will be returned to UI Layer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. What you want to do will depend on whether the performance is acceptable.

Comment: Stored procedure is a good option. If there are no DML statements involved, then it is better to use a function, of course there are no such rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, depending on the capabilities of your service layer, your DB layer and your DB developer ...

1. Create a stored procedure with multiple output `sys_refcursor` parameters; pass the data you need via the cursors to your service layer; have the service layer build the JSON object and send it to your GUI.
2. Create a stored procedure with a single output `sys_refcursor` parameter, which will contain nested refcursor columns with the substructures you need; have the service layer build the JSON object from it and send it to your GUI.
3. Create a stored procedure that builds a complete complex structure in XML; have the service layer transform the XML to JSON and send it to your GUI.
4. Create a stored procedure that builds a complete complex structure in JSON (Oracle 12.1.0.2) and pass it through the service layer to your GUI.
5. Create a view that builds a complex structure in XML; have the service layer query the view for the particular row you need and transform the XML to JSON; ...

Comment: Thanks.Sounds great. Let me try these and revert.